# Declaring items purchased while living abroad, but shipped from US, upon return

Tags: customs-and-immigration

My wife and I have been living in Canada for 4 months on a work permit. We’ll be returning to the US soon, where we are both citizens. The general guidance is that anything we purchased abroad, we need to declare, which we will.

But, we have several items that we shipped from the US to Canada for our use while in Canada - a few articles of clothing, vitamins, that sort of thing. These items are made in the US, and shipped from the US. Do we need to declare these, since we are technically bringing them back into the country?

I assume for items made in the US and purchased in Canada, the usual rules apply (we need to declare theses)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean not to tell the immigration/customs officer about the USA bought items? I would tell about them, have them ready to show, with proof of US purchase. I do not know whether you need to but I rather show and be told it is not needed.

Comment: You can also check your customs process for moving house - most countries have a different process for importing household contents when you're moving to the country after some time abroad